# Facing issue when tried running yarn create react-app client

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

[image]

So when I try to create a react app using yarn I am facing this error. I don't understand why I am receiving this, this is my first time using yarn. It would be great if you could guide me through I want to create a react app with yarn. I face no issues when running npx command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, it can be seen that it is due to the space in your **Windows user name - Adil Asif**. Command prompt takes whatever before `Adil` in the path as command and rest from `Asif` as arguments, instead of `yarn` as command and `create-react-app client` as argument.

You could try using `NPM` or check the corresponding github issue. You can also create project in another drive if available or in the root folder of `C:` drive.

[Github issue and fix](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512#issuecomment-497923059)